# xceed DataGrid CellEditor binding to corresponding row

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, xceed

I have an Xceed DataGrid with some elements. I want property `Email` to be editable according to value of bool property `AllowEmailEdit`.
I tried this, but I couldn't specify correct bindings:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="Email" Title="Email" >
    <xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
        <xcdg:CellEditor>
            <xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowEmailEdit}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:CellEditor.EditTemplate>
        </xcdg:CellEditor>
    </xcdg:Column.CellEditor>
</xcdg:Column>
```

Is this possible some way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it that way:

```
<TextBox
    Text="{xcdg:CellEditorBinding}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, Path=DataContext.AllowEditEmail}"
/>
```